# Не полный перенос строки в потоке ввода

Tags: c++

Нужно отформатировать номер телефона в формате +XXX-YYY-ZZZZZZ и распределить по аргументам номера страны, региона и области, при этом номера между '-' не должны быть пустые, но в номере может быть и не число. Я попытался сделать через поток:

```
stringstream s(international_number);

TestChar(s, '+');

int num = 0;
s >> num;
PhoneNumber::country_code_ = to_string(num);

TestChar(s, '-');

num = 0;
s >> num;
PhoneNumber::city_code_ = to_string(num);

TestChar(s, '-');

getline(s, PhoneNumber::local_number_);
```

Где TestChar:

```
istream& TestChar(istream& s, const char& symb){
if (s.peek() != symb) {
    throw invalid_argument("a");
}
s.ignore();
if (s.peek() != '1' && s.peek() != '2' && s.peek() != '3' && s.peek() != '4' &&
    s.peek() != '5' && s.peek() != '6' && s.peek() != '7' && s.peek() != '8' &&
    s.peek() != '9' && s.peek() != '0') {
    throw invalid_argument("b");
}

return s;
```

Но таким способом в аргументы можно перенести только цифры( даже если убрать проверку на цифры в TestChar, то все равно результат не изменится), т.к, если попытаться перенести из stringstream в string, а не в int, то он переносит туда всю строку из потока. Собственно, в этом и вопрос: можно как-то перенести из потока не всю строку в аргумент?

Comment: имхо, вы слишком усложняете: почему бы просто не записать сразу всю строку в string и уже из нее вытащить всю нужную вам инфу?

Comment: Думал об этом, но отбросил, т.к не совсем четко могу представить, как это сделать, т.к длина чисел не фиксирована

Comment: И? Чем это мешает записать в string?

Comment: В строку это записать не мешает, но как достать оттуда нужные числа и при этом еще определить, пустые они или нет - вот с чем у меня проблема

Comment: `std::getline` с разделителем пробовали?

Comment: если вы не знаете как это сделать через строку, как вы это собрались делать через поток ввода? Лично я вообще не вижу разницы, так как способ работы с данными никак не должен влиять на сами данные.

Comment: А, да, затупил жестко, забыл, что у getline и подобных есть разделитель, спасибо)

Comment: *s.peek() != '1'* -- и дальнейший индусский код - зачем так?

Comment: А больше в голову не приходит, как на числа проверить. Как-то через typeof == int?